# Class of the Reman Warbird Scimitar

Tags: star-trek, spaceship, romulan, star-trek-nemesis

Is there an official class of ship for the Reman Warbird Scimitar? Or is that the one and only of it's class? I have always loved the ship since I first saw it in Star Trek: Nemesis, but other than "Scimitar" I never heard what class it is. Also, if anyone happens to know where to find a cheap/decent model of it I would appreciate the knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In the non-canon video game Star Trek Online, other ships of the same model exist and are referred to as "[Scimitar-class](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Scimitar_class)" dreadnoughts. This is consistent with Star Trek's general policy of ship classes being named after the first ship of that class to be built.

In canon, the *Scimitar* was a one-of-a-kind vessel with no named class.